# My web app needs multiple OAuth consent screen. Do I have to create another project to create another consent screen?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a web app that uses Google Drive API and the end user can choose whether they want to give full access or read-only access (this is crucial).
To my knowledge, you can only create a single OAuth consent screen per project. Since I can't dynamically change the scopes of the screen, does this mean I have to create a new project just for a new OAuth consent screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need a single OAuth consent screen, and a single production project on Google cloud console.  The fact of the matter is that the verification team is not going to be happy verifying your app with two different projects, as was recommended in  another answers.

The instructions from google is each app should have one project for production and one for test / development, the first being verified.

When your app requests authorization of the user you pass the scopes that you request the user to access. What you can do is have two separate buttons one to request read-only access and one to request write access.  The user can then pick which one they want to grant your application access to. Each button requesting the scope that you wish.

If the user changes their mind after granting you read only access and now wants to grant you write access, then you need only include granted scopes pram when you have them grant you access to the new scopes.

## consent screen

Remember that the scopes you configure in the consent screen are just for the verification teams information. They do not effect what is shown in your application when the user clicks consent.   That is configured in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! My thinking was I had to use the scope I defined on the OAuth consent screen settings page. I did not realize you could request a different one from my web app.

Comment: Pro Tip:  When you apply for verification make sure that you tell them in the description box that your app allows the users to pick which scope they want to use.   You have around 1000 characters to describe your use of each scope use the text to explain your use case.    If you have any issues at that time contact me I would be happy to help you can find my contact info in my profile.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can only create one consent screen per project.

This means that there can only be one set of information displayed to users when they first authorize your app. If you need to make changes to your consent screen, you **can't** do it through Terraform or any other automation tool. You'll need to edit the consent screen manually in the GCP Console.

If you want to use same consent screen in multiple projects, yes you can do it.

Comment: -1 your recommendation of more then one project goes against googles instructions in their documentation.  Your not going to be able to verify two apps the cost alone would deter this approach. Not to mention that the verification team would not support it.